# IIS 10 Rewrite Rule adds extra slash (/) on end of rewrite

Tags: iis, http-redirect

I needed to change a folder name on a live site. I need to redirect all requests to that folder (and below it) to the new one.

OLD: https://www.example.com/oldfolder/

OLD: https://www.example.com/oldfolder/subfolder/

OLD: https://www.example.com/oldfolder/subfolder?i=234

to

NEW: https://www.example.com/newfolder/

NEW: https://www.example.com/newfolder/subfolder/

NEW: https://www.example.com/newfolder/subfolder?i=234

The trailing forward slash is desired, but the rewrite is resulting in two trailing slashes:

https://www.example.com/oldfolder redirects to https://www.example.com/newfolder//

The server is IIS 10. Here is the Web.config setting:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" pattern="POST" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
      </rule>

      <rule name="Redirect to /newfolder/ directory" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(oldfolder)(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/newfolder{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

I changed the order of the rules but got the same result. I changed /{R:2} to only {R:2} and still get the same result.

I also don't think my rule is catching /oldfolder/subfolder/ and redirecting to /newfolder/subfolder/

Can anyone see where this extra slash is coming from and how to handle subfolders of the redirected folder?

Comment: Why are you adding the trailing slash before doing the redirection? You can simply create a rule to redirect all requests from the oldfolder to the newfolder.

Comment: I'm adding a trailing slash for the entire site. Just want to redirect the one folder.

Comment: I just tried the rule you provided, but the trailing double slash does not appear. I suggest you try clearing your browser cache and access the URL again.